# Uninterpretable format when trying to list the array's content

Tags: c, arrays

I ran into a problem when I tried to list my Array's content on my new Project. So the problem is that when I list the content of the Array, it writes random numbers instead of the correct content. The counter is working, everything is working well, only this function cannot make a correct output :/

Listing function:

```
typedef struct {
  int cikkszam;
  char nev[40];
  int ar;
} data;

int lista(int listadb, data adat[]) {
  int j = 0;
  int i = 0;
  system("cls");

  for(i = 0; i < listadb; i++) {
    for(j = i + 1; j < listadb; j++) {
      if (adat[i].cikkszam > adat[j].cikkszam) {
        data temp = adat[i];
        adat[i] = adat[j];
        adat[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < listadb; i++) {
    printf ("%-15d \t %-15s \t %-15d\n", adat[i].cikkszam, adat[i].nev, adat[i].ar);
  }

  system("pause");
}
```

And the output is something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVBiP.png)

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your output, put the output in your question. For all we know, the output could be correct, because we don't see how the array passed to `adat` is initialized. The original array might have already garbage to begin with.

Comment: If you have `int main(void) { data adat[5] = { ... }; lista(5, &adat); ... }`, you might get something similar to what you show -- you'd be passing a pointer to an array instead of just an array, and happiness is not the result.  But that's just a guess (and there are obscure technical reasons it may not be a good guess).  If you've coded correctly, that can't be the mistake; you'd have prototype mismatch errors and the code wouldn't compile.  But the problem isn't in the code you show; the problem is in the code you don't show, so we can't help.  Read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: Voting to close since the question does not contain a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Curious that `data` has `char nev[40];`, yet format uses `"%-15s"`.  Recommend using `"%-39.39s"`.

Comment: Problem is likely because un-posted code uses `feof()` and does not check the return values of `fscanf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int cikkszam;
  char nev[40];
  int ar;
} data;

int lista(int listadb, data adat[]) {
  int j = 0;
  int i = 0;
  //system("cls");

  for(i = 0; i < listadb; i++) {
    for(j = i + 1; j < listadb; j++) {
      if (adat[i].cikkszam > adat[j].cikkszam) {
        data temp = adat[i];
        adat[i] = adat[j];
        adat[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < listadb; i++) {
    printf ("%-15d \t %-15s \t %-15d\n", adat[i].cikkszam, adat[i].nev, adat[i].ar);
  }

  //system("pause");
  return 0;
}


int main() {
    data d[] = {
            {1, "abc", 3},
            {4, "def", 5,},
            {567, "fdsaf", -35,},
            {-1231, "aaaaa", 32135,},
            {-333, "bbbb", 654,},
    };
    lista(sizeof(d)/sizeof(d[0]), d);
    return 0;
}
```

Gives me the following output:

```
-1231                aaaaa               32135          
-333                 bbbb                654            
1                    abc                 3              
4                    def                 5              
567                  fdsaf               -35
```

The code you have provided is working correctly. My guess may only be that the error is somewhere outside the source code you have provided.